# Delete duplicate rows in Access SQL-Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

i want to create an Access SQL Query for deleting duplicate rows.

My Table:

```
CustID  EventDate   EventID

12  01.01.2019  1001

10  02.01.2019  1002

11  03.01.2019  1003

10  01.01.2019  1001

11  03.01.2019  1004
```

The table has no primary key. 
I want to delete every duplicate CustID. 
The result should have every CustID once with

**Prio 1**. the most recent EventDate

**Prio 2**. the biggest EventID

The result would look like this:

```
CustID  EventDate   EventID

12  01.01.2019  1001

10  02.01.2019  1002

11  03.01.2019  1004
```

I don't want to use macros.

How would the sql statement look like in access? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming most recent date and biggest event ID will always be in the same record, consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT Table1.CustID, Max([EventDate] & [eventID]) AS ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.CustID;
```

Query2:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Not CustID & EventDate & EventID IN (SELECT CustID & ID
FROM Query1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the conditions for deletion with EXISTS:

```
DELETE FROM tablename AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE 
    CustID = t.CustID 
    AND 
    (EventDate > t.EventDate OR (EventDate = t.EventDate AND EventID > t.EventID))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :

```
Select distinct * into ‪#‎tmpl‬ From MY_TABLE    
Delete from MY_TABLE    
Insert into MY_TABLE    
Select * from #tmpl
Drop table #tmpl
```

While creating temp tables if throw errors, then create another real table and perform the same.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT will not eliminate duplicates because the 3 fields are compound unique identifier. All 5 records are distinct.